# jQuery Dialog Button Text

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery UI to create an AJAX form.
My form is working correctly, however the text attribute of the buttons is not being displayed for some reason.

This is what I am using:

```
$( "#help_form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Send Request",
                id: "submit_help_form",
                click: function() {}
            }
        ]
    });
```

The button is displayed at the bottom of the form, but no text is shown on it.

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/dcgdJ/

Comment: Is that the text really not shown? Or it has the same color with the background?

Comment: It turned out that the site was using an older version of jQuery. I updated to the latest version and it started working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works here, I could see the button label. What browser are you using?
I tried change some parts and it worked too:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#help_form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Send Request":function() {alert(0);} 
            ,"Send Request2":function() {alert(2);} 
        }
    });

    $( "#help_form" ).dialog('open');
});
```